# Как связать загруженные через Ivy *.jar-файлы c проектом

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Я только начал изучать Ant, Ivy. Не могу понять, что нужно сделать для того, чтоб на этапе написания кода были видны скачанные библиотеки.
Используемая IDE IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.6 Ultimate.
Ivy загружаю/устанавливаю Ant'ом с помощью `IvyInstall.xml`.

Структура проекта такая:

```
Src
|
|--ant
|  |--IvyInstall.xml
|  |--Ivy.xml
|  |--TestIvy.xml
|--lib
|--myPkg
|  |--Example.java
```

**IvyInstall.xml**

```
<project name="IvyInstall" default="install-ivy">
<property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${user.home}/.ivy2/jars"/>
<property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar"/>
<property name="ivy.install.version" value="2.2.0"/>

<target name="check-ivy-installed" unless="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists">
    <available property="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists" file="${ivy.jar.file}"/>
</target>

<target name="download-ivy" depends="check-ivy-installed" unless="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists">
    <echo message="downloading and installing ivy"/>
    <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>

    <get src="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar"
         dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
    <echo message="ivy installed"/>
</target>

<target name="install-ivy" depends="download-ivy" description="--> install ivy">
    <echo message="Installing ivy"/>
    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
</target>
```

**Ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info organisation="Src" module="ivy-example" status="integration">
</info>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" />
</dependencies>
```

**testIvy.xml**

```
<project name="testIvy" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
<target name="resolve" description="resolve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" type="jar" pattern="../lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

**Example.java**

```
package myPkg;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class Example {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String string = StringUtils.upperCase("Ivy Beginner Guide");
       System.out.println(string);
   }
}
```

После выполнения `testIvy.xml` Ant'ом, в директории `lib` появляется `commons-lang-2.6.jar`. т.е. `Ant` и `Ivy` делают свое дело и загружают библиотеку.
Но что нужно сделать, чтоб в `Example.java` работал `import`, т.к. после проделанных действий строка импорта:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

IDE ругается на `commons`. Говорит `Cannot resolve symbol commons`. И соответственно ругается на `StringUtils` (дальше по тексту класса).

Растолкуйте, пожалуйста, что к чему.

Comment: Зачем вам Ant и Ivy? Этот выбор сделан осознанно? Сейчас мейнстрим - Maven и Gradle (и Sbt для Scala). Когда используешь Maven, все IDE сами вычисляют зависимости для проекта, не нужно добавлять директории руками.

Comment: В поставленной задаче оговорено использование Ant и Ivy. Приходится разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ, специфичный для IntelliJ IDEA:

- нужно зайти в настройки проекта (File->Project Structure)
- в разделе Modules найти ваш модуль
- на вкладке Dependencies в самом низу нажать на плюсик
- выбрать "JARs or Directories"
- добавить нужную директорию
- PROFIT, можно пересобирать проект

Интерфейс описан для версии EAP 16 для OSX, в версии для Linux и Windows что-то может незначительно отличаться

Comment: т.е. непосредственно для написания кода необходимо все-таки добавлять зависимости в самой IDE, как обычно? А скачанные ANT'ом jar'ники будут использоваться только для сборки?

Comment: самый первый раз дайте анту скачать джарники в lib (вы это уже сделали, насколько я понял). И потом научите Идею брать джарники оттуда. Если состав зависимостей изменился, нужно перезапустить генерацию lib антом, и Идея моментально подхватит изменения. Возможно, есть какой-то более другой способ, но я его не знаю, я больше угорел по maven.

Comment: все так и сделал уже, после перегенерации lib ANT'ом IDE действительно все подтягивает =))
Спасибо, за подсказки!